# Sometimes sprite is pushed away when touches another sprite

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, game-physics, spritebuilder

I am making a game using cocos2d and SpriteBuilder. There is a hero sprite and coins, that should be collected by him. That's a horizontal scrolling game, so every time hero touches a coin, this coin changes it's x-coordinate 2000px to the right and new y-coordinate is generated at random. Using update method I move it to the visible area as a "new" coin. But when hero flyies by and doesn't collect it ,coin must change coordinates only when it's already off the screen, so I tried this solution:

```
-(void)update:(CCTime)delta{



_coin.position=ccp(_coin.position.x - delta * scrollSpeed, _coinY);
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(_hero.boundingBox,_coin.boundingBox)) {
    _coinY=arc4random() % 801 + 100;

    _coin.position=ccp(_coin.position.x + 2000.f,_coinY);

}
else if(_hero.position.x >= _coin.position.x + 150){
    _coinY=arc4random() % 801 + 100;

    _coin.position=ccp(_coin.position.x + 2000.f,_coinY);
}
```

It works,but after that I found a small bug(I am not sure, whether it's related to this code) : sometimes, when hero touches coin, hero is like pushed away to the left. I have no idea why.

1. How to fix it?
2. Is that way, that I am using for coin ,right?

Comment: It looks like your hero just collides with the coing and bounces back. Do you use physics to detect collisions? If so, did you set your coin to be sensor?

Comment: I thought, that nothing should happen by default, when two sprites collide. I use CGRectIntersectsRect to detect collision. Also I set density,friction,elasticity to zero in SpriteBuilder. I am not sure, what you mean by "sensor", but maybe it is sensor, because that code works fine, and bugs by collison appear sometimes only.

Comment: You need to show at least the code you use to determine and react to the player touching the coin. It looks like the only thing being shown is a hack aimed at covering up the problem.

Comment: Do you check "Enable physics" in SpriteBuilder for both hero and coin? I guess you are, otherwise density, friction and elasticity can't be changed.

Comment: @KirillMuzykov Sure,it's enabled. Otherway collision would not happen at all. it works in my case, but SOMETIMES hero's coordinates are changed a little bit after collision.

Comment: @KirillMuzykov Ваша книга есть на русском языке?

Comment: I've created an answer because it didn't fit into comment. No, the book is only in English :( Sorry for not replying in Russian, but I think there is a rule about this somewhere in StackExchange FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 issues with your approach:

**1. Hero bounces of the coin.**

To fix this you need to make your coin a [sensor](http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/Classes/CCPhysicsBody.html#//api/name/sensor). This way you will still be notified about collisions, but the hero will simply pass through the coin without actually hitting it.

I'm not sure if you can set this in SpriteBuilder, but probably you can enumerate all coins after loading the scene and set `sensor` property to `YES`:

```
coin.physicsBody.sensor = YES;
```

Things like this is one of the reasons I believe you first need to learn pure Cocos2D and only then use tools making your life easier such as SpriteBuilder. Which is a great tool, but in some cases you still need know what happens behind the scenes.

**2. You're mixing physics with things like `CGRectIntersectsRect`**

If you're using physics engine you need to detect collisions via [collision delegate](http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/Protocols/CCPhysicsCollisionDelegate.html) and not by checking `CGRectIntersectsRect` in `update:`.

It is hard to explain how to do this in a few sentences, so here is a nice [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/61391/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-3-0-tutorial) that shows how to detect collisions in Cocos2D v3 and of course there is a chapter about this in [my book](http://kirillmuzykov.com/my-cocos2d-book-published/).

By the way you shouldn't use `update:`at all when manipulating physics nodes, use `fixedUpdate:` instead.

I hope this will help you to solve your issue.